# Как добавить HTML разметку в PHP функцию

Tags: php, html, синтаксис

Есть функция склонения числительных. Стили срабатывают, но останавливают функцию:

```
echo function('<div class="style">'.$var.'</div>',array('1', '2', '3'));
```

Понимаю, что синтаксис неверный, и хочу спросить, можно ли исправить его в этой строке? Спасибо.

Comment: Саму функцию покажите пожалуйста. Возвращает она что-то?

Comment: наверное там надо использовать <?php //код ?>

Comment: Функция такая: 

function decl($number, $titles)
{
    $cases = array (2, 0, 1, 2);
    return $number." ".$titles[ ($number%100 > 4 && $number %100 < 20) ? 2 : $cases[min($number%10, 5)] ];
}

echo 'Опубликовано '.decl($num, array('статья', 'статьи', 'статей'));

Comment: В данном случае нужно выделить переменную $num

Comment: так может надо результат функции обернуть в стили, а не переменную-то ? `echo "<div>" . func() . "</div>"` ?

Comment: Так-то работает, но мне нужно выделить именно цифру, результат до массива, поэтому пробовал по переменной

Comment: @user238122 так может, вам стилями стоит обвести переменную $number прямо внутри функции?

Comment: что за странное желание в вызове функции использовать литералы? захочешь называть не сообщениями, а постами - будешь искать строчку с этим вызовом вместо переопределение значения переменной.

Comment: зачем вы вообще передаете html разметку в код, когда у вас функция decl принимать должна просто принимает число и варианты склонения слова? что за функция function у вас?

Answer (score 0):

Получилось как раз добавлением стиля при возвращении:

```
   return '<div class="style">'.$number."</div>
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: сомнительная идея смешивать обработку в php и разметку в функциях.